# How can I implement variant types in the CLR/Managed C++?

Tags: c#, clr, managed-c++, variant

In the .net CLR Object is the base for all class objects, but not basic types (e.g. int, float etc). How can I use basic types like Object?
I.e. Like [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/variant.html)?

E.g. *like* :-

```
object intValue( int(27) );
if (intValue is Int32)
    ...

object varArray[3];
varArray[0] = float(3.141593);
varArray[1] = int(-1005);
varArray[2] = string("String");
```

Comment: This is in .net 2.0. I think 3.0 is more dynamic so maybe that is possible there but I only have VS2005 which can't use .net 3.0.

Comment: C# 3.0 is what you're thinking of, and it's not really more dynamic. The "var" keyword you've seen does not create variants, just inferred types. var i = 1; still makes "i" an int.

Comment: @Nick: 3.0 is no more dynamic than 2.0; C# 3.0 has "var", but that isn't "variant" - it is "variable", meaning "infer the type automatically". It is still static typed. C# 4.0 introduces "dynamic"

Comment: Sorry, I actually have to do this in Managed C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`object`, via boxing, is the effective (root) base-class of all .NET types. That should work fine - you just need to use `is` or `GetType()` to check the types...

```
object[] varArray = new object[3];
varArray[0] = 3.141593F;
varArray[1] = -1005;
varArray[2] = "String";
```

Comment: I'm actually using Managed C++ and this doesn't compile. I think anything possible in C# should be possible in MC++ though?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have the right syntax for returning a boxed value in managed C++.

Comment: Yep, it was my fault. I have a c# GUI using a MC++ lib and I need to do the same thing in both but I couldn't get the syntax right for MC++.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned you're in C++/CLI, you should be able to do:

```
array<Object^>^ varArray =  gcnew array<Object^>(3);

varArray[0] = 3.141593;
varArray[1] = -1005;
varARray[2] = "String";

double val = *reinterpret_cast<double^>(varArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
object varArray[3] = new object[3];
varArray[0] = 3.141593;
varArray[1] = -1005;
varArray[2] = "String";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the boxing answer. I need to box my return value, e.g.

```
    Object ^ createFromString(String ^ value)
    {
         Int32 i( Convert::ToInt32(value) );
         return static_cast< Object ^ >(i);
    }
```

I need to box the return value by casting to an Object pointer. Intuitive! :)

And retrieve as:

```
    void writeValue(Object ^ value, BinaryWriter ^ strm)
    {
        Int32 i( *dynamic_cast< Int32 ^ >(value) );
        strm->Write(i);
    }
```